# Responsive design doesn't work on IPhone only

Tags: css, ios, iphone, responsive-design, adaptive-design

I'm working on a responsive website project, but because of some reason the media query doesn't work on IPhone(while it works perfectly on other devices).
Since I have quite a lot of code, I created a new empty HTML file to show the issue. In the following example the background-color is not changing if I open the website on IPhone.
The page is: https://dobrocenter.fi/test.html
Where is the issue and how to solve it? Thank you!
Here is my HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
       <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And CSS:

```
 body{
       background-color: #000;
    }
    @media(435px>=width) {
       body{
          background-color: #e64f4f;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `@media only screen and (min-width: 435px)`?

Comment: nothing changes, still not working

Comment: Which iPhone is it and what background are you expecting to see as a result? I assume from the phrasing of the question you are expecting red on the phone? From https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ iPhones have many different breakpoints. Maybe try some of those values depending on your device?

Comment: As far as i understand the iPhone's model itself doesn't matter. But IOS version matters. It didn't work on my(14 pro) iPhone, but then I updated the version of IOS, now it works. But it still doesn't work on other iPhones(I tested it on my friends' phones). So unfortunately I can't ask all users to update their IOS and I still need to fix it somehow...